# Gerar arquivo D-1

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, data

Como realizo o select de dados no formato D-1 (dia atual - 1), o que seria no VBA um `AGORA() - 1`, como seria isto no postgreSQL?

Tenho a query a seguir e gostaria de pegar o dia de ontem para gerar relatórios.

```
select * 
from 
    ivr_contatos, 
    ivr_campanha,
    ivr_business 
where ivr_campanha.id = '1' 
    and ivr_contatos.campanha = '1' 
    and ivr_business.idvisita = ivr_contatos.codigo 
    and ivr_contatos.status = 0 
    and tentativas >= qtdtentativas 
    and date();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser utilizado o `CURRENT_DATE` que retorna a data atual. Se precisar da data e hora utilize o `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
select * 
from 
    ivr_contatos, 
    ivr_campanha,
    ivr_business
where ivr_campanha.id = '1' 
    and ivr_contatos.campanha = '1' 
    and ivr_business.idvisita = ivr_contatos.codigo 
    and ivr_contatos.status = 0 
    and tentativas >= qtdtentativas 
    and nome_do_campo = CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 day';
```

Existem outras possibilidades como a de definir o intervalo (`interval`) que você quer adicionar ou subtrair na sua consulta, se por exemplo você precisar da data do mês anterior, poderia realizar a consulta conforme abaixo:

```
select * 
from 
    ivr_contatos, 
    ivr_campanha,
    ivr_business
where ivr_campanha.id = '1' 
    and ivr_contatos.campanha = '1' 
    and ivr_business.idvisita = ivr_contatos.codigo 
    and ivr_contatos.status = 0 
    and tentativas >= qtdtentativas 
    and nome_do_campo = CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 month';
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: Realizando desta primeira forma, ele me retorna o erro argument of AND must be type boolean, not type date.

Comment: Esqueci de colocar o nome do campo que seria filtrado rsrs. Também adicionei o interval no primeiro comando, que é a forma mais correta.

Comment: Ah sim.. ai eu entro em outro problema, eu não tenho um campo especifico que sirva como ''base'' de data, eu apenas queria todos os dados gerados na data do dia anterior ao dia atual.

Comment: Mas você precisa definir o campo para que o postgres saiba quais registros ele tem que filtrar. Se for mais de um campo você vai adicionando com o AND ou OR, a depender da sua regra de negócio, mas tem q definir qual coluna receberá o filtro.

Comment: Certo, entendi a solução. vou verificar qual campo que posso utilizar, agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Você pode utilizar os valores especiais do PostgreSQL: YESTERDAY E TOMORROW. Rode o seguinte teste: SELECT CURRENT_DATE, 'YESTERDAY'::date AS "Ontem", 'TOMORROW':: date AS "Amanhã";